# Create arrays of random letters: Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, numpy

Using the function below it is more convenient to create an array of random integers.

```
def generate_random_strings(x, i, j):

    return np.random.randint(0, 2, size=[x, i, j]).astype(np.float32)

print (generate_random_strings(3, 5, 4))

[[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 1. 1. 0.]
[0. 1. 1. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 1.]
[0. 1. 0. 1.]]

[[0. 1. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 1. 1.]
[0. 1. 1. 0.]
[1. 0. 1. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0.]]

[[0. 0. 1. 0.]
[1. 0. 1. 1.]
[0. 0. 0. 1.]
[0. 1. 0. 0.]
[1. 1. 0. 0.]]]
```

I tried to build similar function as above for letters (a-z) instead of integers, but i couldn't find any built-in functions from numpy or any other available libraries.

So i used 3 - for loops as below,

```
# Generate random letter
def randomword(len):
    return random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)

x= 3
i= 5
j= 4

buf = []

for _ in range(x):
    bu = []
    for i in range(i):
        b = []
        for j in range(j):
            b.append(randomword(1))
        bu.append(b)
    buf.append(np.asarray(bu))

print(np.asarray(buf))

[[['u' 'w' 'w' 'x']
  ['b' 's' 'p' 'a']
  ['k' 'u' 'y' 'p']
  ['p' 'z' 'b' 'u']
  ['o' 'h' 'c' 'm']]

 [['t' 'y' 'b' 'r']
  ['e' 's' 'e' 't']
  ['p' 'n' 'd' 'w']
  ['h' 'f' 'i' 'e']
  ['o' 'b' 'q' 'r']]

 [['x' 'z' 'd' 'x']
  ['r' 'b' 'f' 'b']
  ['d' 'h' 'e' 'g']
  ['p' 'g' 'u' 'x']
  ['k' 'j' 'z' 'd']]]
```

So, now my question is , is there any function as `np.random.randint()` for strings/letters, if no then, is there any pythonic way to reduce(for loops) the code length.

Comment: `chr(randint(97, 122))`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `numpy.choice` on all ascii lower case letters:

```
import string
import numpy as np

np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase),  size=(3, 5,4))
```

Comment: does numpy have all "normal" random-module methods? choice/choices seems to be in one, what about sample or randint?

Comment: @PatrickArtner See [`numpy.random`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html).

Comment: Note, `list(string.ascii_lowercase)` is not necessary, you just need `string.ascii_lowercase`

Comment: have to stop being lazy and search for some good numpy tuts *mumble* thanks @miradulo - that link is great.#

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No, it should be an array.

Comment: @liliscent missed that they were using `np`, so it has to be array-like, yes

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick to numpy, you can use the `'S1'` data-type, which are just length-1 byte-strings. So, the `ord` corresponds to the same number as an 8-bit unsigned integer. So you *could* use `numpy.random.randint` to generate random unsigned 8-bit integers, and *cast them to byte-strings*:

```
>>> ord('a'), ord('z')
(97, 122)
>>> np.random.randint(97, 123, (3, 5, 4), dtype=np.uint8).view('S1')
array([[[b'p', b'q', b'b', b'x'],
        [b'm', b'x', b'e', b'f'],
        [b'u', b'h', b'e', b'd'],
        [b'o', b'n', b'w', b'v'],
        [b'z', b'q', b'g', b'e']],

       [[b'f', b'o', b'c', b'j'],
        [b'z', b'x', b'l', b'x'],
        [b'u', b'f', b'w', b'r'],
        [b'q', b'z', b'm', b'o'],
        [b't', b'e', b'm', b'e']],

       [[b'f', b'i', b'x', b'k'],
        [b'z', b'w', b'm', b'g'],
        [b't', b'f', b'u', b'q'],
        [b'e', b'w', b'w', b'r'],
        [b'e', b'q', b'a', b'g']]],
      dtype='|S1')
```

Note, it is twice as fast and requires one-quarter the memory:

```
In [8]: %timeit np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase),  size=(10, 10, 10))
24.8 µs ± 311 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [9]: %timeit np.random.randint(97, 123, (10, 10, 10), dtype=np.uint8).view('S1')
7.45 µs ± 95.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase),  size=(10, 100, 10))
116 µs ± 2.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [11]: %timeit np.random.randint(97, 123, (10, 100, 10), dtype=np.uint8).view('S1')
53.4 µs ± 641 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [12]: %timeit np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase),  size=(10, 100, 100))
993 µs ± 8.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [13]: %timeit np.random.randint(97, 123, (10, 100, 100), dtype=np.uint8).view('S1')
503 µs ± 6.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [14]: %timeit np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase),  size=(100, 100, 100))
9.99 ms ± 58.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [15]: %timeit np.random.randint(97, 123, (100, 100, 100), dtype=np.uint8).view('S1')
5.06 ms ± 129 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Somewhat less clear but this will likely be faster. Any reason for wrapping with `np.dtype`?

Comment: @miradulo not sure what you mean. You mean "np.dtype('S1')"? well, you need to precisely define the dtype. `np.str` won't work, and isn't really correct.

Comment: Sorry I just meant removing `np.dtype`. `view('S1')`... the dtype is the first parameter.

Comment: @miradulo ah, no reason, just my first inclination.

Comment: @miradulo yeah, the speed really wouldn't be the main advantage I would espouse, rather, it is the much more efficient use of space. A U1 dtype requires 4 bytes, versus 1 byte for S1.

Answer (score 2):

Create as many random letters as you need and reshape them into a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
import string
import random

def randomLetters(amount:int):
    return random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=amount)    

i=5
j=4
x=3

d =  np.array(randomLetters(x*i*j)).reshape((x,i,j))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print [[[chr(randint(ord('a'), ord('z'))) for col in range(4)]for row in range(5)] for x in range(3)]
```

The output:

```
[
[
    ['e', 'y', 'y', 'a'],
    ['p', 'o', 'k', 'z'],
    ['j', 'p', 'n', 'p'],
    ['d', 'y', 'k', 's'],
    ['k', 'c', 'k', 'o']
],
[
    ['v', 'w', 't', 'a'],
    ['f', 'a', 't', 'm'],
    ['h', 'w', 'i', 'x'],
    ['a', 'w', 's', 'z'],
    ['x', 'f', 'b', 'b']
],
[
    ['x', 'f', 'm', 'y'],
    ['b', 'u', 'z', 's'],
    ['j', 'p', 'x', 'l'],
    ['a', 'p', 'b', 'i'],
    ['z', 's', 'v', 'k']
]
]
```

Comment: because `ord('a')` and `ord('z')` are less magical then 97 and 122 - and the less magic numbers the better